# The ending of "The Dead Astronaut"

Tags: the-dead-astronaut

I just read ["The Dead Astronaut" (1968)](http://unlimited-ebooks.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/3/9/13397081/_ballard_james_graham_-_the_dead_astronaut.pdf) written by J.G.Ballard.

I don't quite understand its ending.

What does the protagonist try to ask his wife about?  And what does he learn from her facial expression?

Comment: Author tags are saved for questions specifically about said author :)

Comment: Got it! Thank you! :)

Comment: Nice question though!

Comment: Full text here; http://unlimited-ebooks.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/3/9/13397081/_ballard_james_graham_-_the_dead_astronaut.pdf

Comment: Presumably, whether she had been unfaithful with the astronaut.

Answer (score 2):

This is one interpretation. There are certainly others.

The story has two sides. One is Hamilton's. He and Judith fell in love. They probably would have married, if he had come back from his ill-fated mission.

The other is Groves's. With Hamilton dead, he married Judith, even though she never stopping grieving.

His question, the one he never asked in twenty years of waiting, is which man Judith would have married if Hamilton had lived.

He is about to die, just as Judith is, because of Hamilton and a secret program. The betrayal is on Hamilton's part, for his participation in the program and for repaying her devotion with radiation poisoning. Groves is surprised, just as she is. When he says "I used him," he means that he took advantage of her feelings about Hamilton to deflect any misgivings she might have about him.

His answer is that Hamilton died without telling her about his last mission, that he never came home, that he got revenge from beyond the grave. The man who brought them together will separate them forever. Judith will die loving Groves wholeheartedly.

Comment: This is more or less what I thought, but I still don't see how he used her obsession to his advantage. Perhaps it's due to different cultures? It sounds very weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of it, given the timing of the miscarriage and Robert being lost in space, and the description of the obsession, is that Robert was having an affair with Judith at the time of his death, and might have been the father of the child. Phillip suspected it, and caused the accident. He basically admits his guilt and is asking if they really were having an affair. Her look of betrayal betrays how deeply she cared for Robert, confirming his suspicions.

> Robert Hamilton was carrying an atomic weapon!" I pulled back the curtains from the window. "My God, what a joke. For twenty years, I put up with him because I couldn't ever be really sure…"
>   "Philip…"
>   "Don't worry, I used him – thinking about him was the only thing that kept us going. And all the time, he was waiting up there to pay us back!"

....

> "Judith, before we go, tell me… I never asked you –"
>   Judith was sitting up, touching the hair on her pillow. One half of her scalp was almost bald. She stared at her weak hands with their silvering skin. On her face was an expression I had never seen before, the dumb anger of betrayal.
>   As she looked at me, and at the bones scattered across the table, I knew my answer.

Comment: You mean Philip poisoned Robert with some radioactive matter? Why did he say "don't worry, I used him"?

Comment: @KinzleB: I think Philip sabotaged the launch. And he "used him" by maintaining this mutual obsession with Judith over Robert. All the while, he felt guilty because he really didn't know if he'd killed Robert for no reason. Now, after Robert's posthumous revenge, the only remaining thing for him to do is determine whether he was "right" to have killed him.

Comment: Did you miss this part: "Three hours after lift-off, a freak meteorite collision ruptured his oxygen support system. He had lived on in his suit for another five hours. Although calm at first, his last radio transmissions were an incoherent babble Judith and I had never been allowed to hear."?

Comment: @KinzleB:
{nods} Except the odds of the meteorite itself being observed would be low, so that was probably the conclusion drawn as to why where would have been, say, a sudden loud noise at one side of the capsule followed by a failure of systems there. It could as well have been a poorly tightened panel, an overloaded system, or something more nefarious.

Comment: Why did they need her obsession to keep them going? Without it, what would happen?

Comment: @KinzleB: Without her obsession, not only would Judith lack passion in her life, but also it would eliminate the one major thing they hold in common (even if, in his case, he may be faking it to some degree), which would give her little reason to stay.

Comment: I realized Robert's revenge was not intentional if what you said was true. Right?

Comment: Correct. It was Karmic revenge.